# Javascript - Find an replace a part of a string with value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an string, but at certain points in the string it has dynamic values.
I want to find those points in the string and replace them with values from an array.

Let's say I have:

```
var array = ['string', 'value'];
var string = 'This is a {1}, and this is a {2}.';
```

Now I need to figure out a way to replace {1}, with the value of the first index in the array and replace {2} with the value of the second index of the array.

So the string would like this:

```
This is a string, and this is a value.
```

This seems so simple, but I am breaking my head on this. I can't find a way to do this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression and a function:

```
string.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, n) {
  return array[n-1];
});
```

You can also check `n < 1 || n > array.length` to provide a fallback value in case the number is out of bounds.

Alternatively, the new ES6 way is using [tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings)

```
function tag(strings, ...values) {
  var parts = [];
  for(var i=0; i<strings.length; ++i)
    parts.push(strings[i], array[values[i]-1]);
  return parts.join('');
}
tag`This is a ${1}, and this is a ${2}.`
```

Comment: When I use your first example, the '{' and '}' are still in the string, though the 1 and 2 are replaced properly.

Comment: The match variable contains either '{1}' or '{2}', but only the value itself is replaced and not the brackets.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now it works. Apparently, somewhere in my code that made the string, it added two {{ and two }}, instead of one. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var StringHelper = {
  format: function(format, args) {
    return args.reduce(function(result, currentReplace, currentReplaceIndex) {
      result = result.replace("{" + (currentReplaceIndex + 1) + "}", args[currentReplaceIndex]);

      return result;
    }, format);
  }
};

var sourceString = "My name is {1} and I'm {2} years old";
var replaceItems = ["Matías", "31"];

var parsedString = StringHelper.format(sourceString, replaceItems);

alert(parsedString);
```

It's a good alternative to regular expressions, and I'm not absolutely sure if I did a [*jsPerf* test](http://jsperf.com/string-replace-vs-string-replace-with-regex/3) in the right way, but it shows that this approach outperforms the regular expression one.

Comment: This also worked for me, though I prefer the accepted answer.

Comment: @DijkeMark I believe you don't know the power of *encapsulation*. Check my updated answer which generalizes the solution into an object function.

Comment: @DijkeMark If you can't use ES6 or above, that simple string formatting function is the closest solution to your issue and as I said, it seems like it outperforms regular expressions. BTW I'll leave my answer for further readers.

Comment: I see, thank you for this explanation. I will keep it in mind for further cases.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
string.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(m, n){
  return array[n-1]
})
```

Comment: When I use your first example, the '{' and '}' are still in the string, though the 1 and 2 are replaced properly.